# EasyAdmin (v2): filter list view by the property of a related entity

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I am willing to implement exactly the kind of list filtering that is described in EasyAdmin (v.2) documentation on Symfony ([Custom dynamic filters](https://symfony.com/doc/2.x/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/list-search-show-configuration.html#dynamic-filters-filters-option)), i.e. filtering the list view of an entity by the property of a related entity (e.g. list orders by customers of a given country).

With only the following code blocks available in the doc I am quite lost on how to create a custom EntityTypeFilter with the usual two select lists (is same/is not same list & list of available Country for Order via the Customer association). What should be in the `configureOptions()` and `getParent()` functions?

Thanks !

```
# config/packages/easy_admin.yaml
easy_admin:
    entities:
        Users:
            class: App\Entity\Order
            list:
                filters:
                    # 'country' doesn't exist as a property of 'Order' so it's
                    # defined as 'not mapped' to avoid errors
                    - property: 'country'
                      type: 'App\Form\Filter\CustomerCountryFilterType'
                      mapped: false
```

```
// App\Form\Filter\CustomerCountryFilterType
// ...

public function filter(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, FormInterface $form, array $metadata)
{
    if (null !== $form->getData()) {
        $queryBuilder
            ->leftJoin('entity.customer', 'customer')
            ->andWhere('customer.country = :country')
            ->setParameter('country', $form->getData());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
// ...

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'class' => Country::class
    ]);
}

public function getParent()
{
    return EntityType::class;
}
```

If you want to sort by country name, you can add a custom query builder to the options:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
// ...

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'class' => Country::class,
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
        }
    ]);
}
```